# Start-ThreadJob: Cannot bind argument to parameter because it is an empty string

Tags: powershell

Trying to run Robocopy in parallel:

```
function Invoke-Robocopy {
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Source,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$Target,
    [string]$File = $null
  )
  $common_args = (
    '/dcopy:dat', '/r:2', '/w:5', '/log+:robocopy.log', '/mt:2',
    '/ns', '/nc', '/nfl', '/ndl', '/np'
  )
  if (-Not $File) {
    $common_args += ('/e', '/purge')
  }
  robocopy "$Source" "$Target" "$File" $common_args
}
$dir_pairs = (
  ('O:\projects', 'N:\projects'),
  ("$env:SystemRoot\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine", 'N:\sys\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine'),
  ("$env:SystemRoot\System32\GroupPolicy\User", 'N:\sys\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User')
)
foreach ($pair in $dir_pairs) {
  Start-ThreadJob -InputObject $pair {
    ${Function:Invoke-Robocopy} = ${using:Function:Invoke-Robocopy}
    Write-Host "$($input[0]) $($input[1])"
    $robo_args = @{
      Source = $input[0]
      Target = $input[1]
    }
    Invoke-Robocopy @robo_args
  } | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
}
```

But for every folder (`$pair`) it throws an `Invoke-Robocopy : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Target' because it is an empty string` error, ironically right after printing the parameter strings.

I'm thinking this might be caused by thread jobs and has something to do with scopes.
That, or `$input[0]` and `$input[1]` aren't strings.. which wouldn't make sense because how else would they be printed?